# Mixins with Akka

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, akka

I have an actor to which I want inject dependency using mixin. Code:

```
trait ProductsAware {
   def getProducts: List[Product]
}

trait MyActor extends Actor with ProductsAware {
   val products = getProducts  
...
}
```

As you can see I'm just trying to decouple `MyActor` from concrete instance of `ProductsAware` trait, and provide concrete instance in other place (when creating actor).

And this is concrete implementation of `ProductsAware` trait:

```
trait ProductsAwareFirstImpl {
  override def getProducts = {List(new Product())}
}
```

And I want to create new `MyActor` and inject to `MyActor` this concrete implementation `ProductsAwareFirstImpl`:

```
system.actorOf(Props[MyActor])
```

The problem is that is not safe at compile time, i.e. anyone can forget to mix the `ProductsAwareFirstImpl`to `MyActor`

Comment: Looks like feature request for akka

Answer (score 0):

You can use a different Actor Props construction technique, namely the `Props(new Actor)` as [documented here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/actors.html). Just make sure you are careful and not closing over any state, e.g. putting it in a object and calling it via a method should be safe. This is described in the documentation, but a quick mockup would look like this:

```
object MyActor { 
  def newActorWithFirstImpl = new MyActor with ProductsAwareFirstImpl
}
//...
system.actorOf(Props(MyActor.newActorWithFirstImpl))
```

Answer (score 0):

To be sure that some trait is mixed to you actor you may user [explicit self type reference](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/explicitly-typed-self-references.html):

```
trait MyActor extends Actor {
    self: ProductsAware =>

    val products = getProducts
    //  ...
}
```

So no one could instantiate `MyActor` without mixin `ProductsAware`

Comment: actors initiated like `actorOf(Props[MyActor])`, i.e. without creating actual instance, so it's not compile time error. Look at @Akos answer